# JAGS cannot handle small exponential value?

Tags: jags, r2jags

I had a weird problem using JAGS for Bayesian data analysis. 
Say in a loop, I have

```
for (i in 1:10) {
   A[i] <- B[i]*exp(-C[i])
}
```

whenever C[i] is large and results in exp(-C[i]) smaller than 10^-16, A[i] takes the value of A[i-1].
It looks like JAGS cannot handle the small exponential value, but 10^-16 isn't a small number.

Comment: I have a temporary workaround for this problem. Use the log function on both side of the equation and transform the scales. But still, I don't quite get it why the exponential function has a trouble for a number less than 1e-16, which is about exp(-36).